# How to send old version of the field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

I use JEditable for making edit field which following code:

```
       $(function() {
                $(".field").editable("http://localhost/index.php/welcome/update_record", { 
                event  : "mouseover",
                style  : "inherit",
                submit : "save",
                callback: function(value, settings) {
                    //some code
                    }
                });  
    });
```

I need to update value of the field in the database, but if an user hasn't entered into system with his login/password pair, I need to show message about it and return an old value of the field. So, how can I send the old value of the string too? How can I add it to $_POST array? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go - will do it for more than one at a time:

```
$(function() {
     $(".field").each(function() {
            var old_value = $(this).text(); //save old value
            $(this).editable("http://localhost/index.php/welcome/update_record", { 
            event  : "mouseover",
            style  : "inherit",
            submit : "save",
            callback: function(value, settings) {
                    $(this).text(old_value);
                }
            }); 
     });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you mean by the old string? If you mean the value of field before you made it editable, simply save that value in a variable:

```
$(function() {
            var old_value = $(".field").text(); //save old value

            $(".field").editable("http://localhost/index.php/welcome/update_record", { 
            event  : "mouseover",
            style  : "inherit",
            submit : "save",
            callback: function(value, settings) {
                //do something with old_value here
                }
            });  
});
```

Edit: If its a textfield and not a container - use $(".field").val(); instead of text.

Comment: Also, please, tell me, how can I set the value into the field in callback function?

Comment: I am not familiar with the plugin, but i assume `$(this).text(old_value);` in the callback function will do it.

Comment: Sorry, but your solution doesn't work. Because field is name of the class, but I need id.

Comment: if there is more than one you want to attach it to, wrap the whole thing in a `$(".field").each()` - ill write it out in another answer.

Comment: Yes, there are about 20 fields with "field" class name. I need to get old value for field by which I click.